# $\mathscr{M}_*$, the stack of generalized elliptic curves (with some additional conditions) is locally of finite presentaion

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

Let $\mathscr{M}_*$ be the stack over $\mathbb{Z}$ which classifies generalized elliptic curves $E/S$, such that for every geometric point $k$ of $\mathbb{Z}$, the fibre $E_k$ is smooth or $n$-gon, where $\mathrm{char} k$ does not divide $n$.
(see III.0. of Deligne-Rapoport's "Les schemas de modules de courbes elliptiques")

In III.2.5., the authors claim that $\mathscr{M}_*$ is locally of finite presentation as a fibred category, i.e., for any direct limit of rings $A = \lim A_i$, the canonical map $\lim \mathscr{M}_* (A_i) \to \mathscr{M}_*(A)$ is an equivalence.
They say that this is EGA IV.8.8.

Using it (and some propositions in Stack Project), we can show, for a generalized elliptic curve $E/A$, that there exist an $i$, a proper flat curve $E_i / A_i$, and morphism $E_i^\text{sm} \times E_i \to E_i$, which induce the ones of $E/A$.
But I can't show that for some $i$, this $E_i/A_i$ is a generalized elliptic cuvre.

If for some $i$ $E_i/A_i$ has reduced geometric fibres, then we can show that this $E_i/A_i$ has connected geometric fibres.
And it seems that I can show for some $i$, every geometric fibre of $E_i/A_i$ has the trivial dualizing sheaf.
(First assume $A_i$ noether. Then $\operatorname{Spce} A_i$ has an connected open subset which intersects the image of $\operatorname{Spec}A$.
Thus using the Picard scheme of $E_i \times U / U$, we can show the subset "$\{\omega = \mathscr{O} \}$" of $U$ is clopen.)

So finally, I want to show that for some $i$, every geometric fibre of $E_i/A_i$ is reduced, and whose singularity is at least ordinary double.
(If so, then by the argument above and II.1.13., we have that this $E_i/A_i$ is a generalized elliptic curve.)

I can't find it in EGA.
So please suggest me some references of it, or please prove it.

Comment: Remark 2.1.16 in Cesnavicius's article https://www.imo.universite-paris-saclay.fr/~cesnavicius/modular-description.pdf seems to go in that direction, though I have not checked.

Comment: See, for instance, Proposition 2.3 of the following: https://arxiv.org/pdf/0809.5224.pdf